# Why does my boost::filesystem::ofstream not work with std::ios_base::out?

Tags: c++, boost, stream, boost-filesystem, gzip

I want to read a .gz file, decompress it to and write the new file again using streams and boost::filesystem.

I encountered an issue where the ofstream stream was not able to write the compressed file and exited with an exception.

I found a solution but I can't tell why it is working: switching std::ios_base::out to std::ios_base::binary for the osstream.

Can someone explain me why this is working or why an exception was thrown with std::ios_base::out?

```
void decrompressGzFile(const std::string& pathToFile, const std::string
pathToConvertedFile)
{
    boost::filesystem::path path{ pathToFile };
    boost::filesystem::ifstream inStream(pathToFile, 
        std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

    boost::filesystem::ofstream outStream(pathToConvertedFile, std::ios_base::binary); //working
   //boost::filesystem::ofstream outStream(path, std::ios_base::out); //gzip error: iostream stream error

    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> decompressStream;
    decompressStream.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    decompressStream.push(inStream);

    try
    {
        boost::iostreams::copy(decompressStream, outStream);

    } catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: By default all files are opened in *text* mode. On some platforms (typically Windows) that could lead to some translations of characters sequences into other character sequences (like for example `"\r\n"` into `"\n"` when reading, and the opposite when writing). For a binary file such translations lead to corrupt data as the data you read or write is no longer correct if the data happen to contain such special character sequences.

Comment: This sounds legit. When is ios_base::out / base::in used? Mostly in Linux?

Comment: You can combine `std::ios::out` and `std::ios::binary`: `std::ios::out | std::ios::binary`. For making portable code which writes a binary file, I would recommend to do this always. Thus, it will work properly on Windows, and it doesn't hurt on Linux (and other *ix systems) where it simply has no effect. (Btw. the same applies for reading files respectively.)